# Image orientation issue AVCaptureOutput delegate iOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, avfoundation, face-detection

I'm working on the face detection functionality and getting buffer in the delegate below but when I try to make UIImage with CIImage, I'm getting image in Landscape code, I have only portrait orientation in app:

1)- On generating session, tried to make portrait mode:

```
 // previewLayer is kind of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    if ([self.previewLayer.connection isVideoOrientationSupported])
        [self.previewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
```

2)- Delegate:

```
    - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
        didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

3)-  Unable to rotate UIImage as image.CGImage is nil

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

        ///CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = [self rotateBuffer:sampleBuffer];

        CFDictionaryRef attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
        CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer
                                                          options:(__bridge NSDictionary *)attachments]; 
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage];
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with orientation of image that I get from delegate, I tried with multiple code snaps of stack overflow answers but none of them worked to rotate image or buffer, some are:

[iOS app camera orientation in captureOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398029/ios-app-camera-orientation-in-captureoutput)

[Rotate CGImage taken from video frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355070/rotate-cgimage-taken-from-video-frame)

[How to directly rotate CVImageBuffer image in IOS 4 without converting to UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528879/how-to-directly-rotate-cvimagebuffer-image-in-ios-4-without-converting-to-uiimag)

Comment: You could try Smerk. https://github.com/MattFoley/Smerk